# Create a facebook app with a page account

Tags: php, facebook-apps

Is it possible to create a facebook app with a page account instead of a personal one? We have created the page of our company and we want to use it to create the facebook app for login into our website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Have one of the page admins create the app instead.

Comment: just what I thought. Thank you :)